# How can I insert a line break , render html for text in VUE?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I got a string coming to frontend like this `comeoutside`

But in html I need to render this with a condition

```
const separateFirstFourWords = (words) => {
  let newStr = `${words.substring(0, 4)} <br> ${words.substring(4,words.length)}`;
  return newStr;
};

<p>{{something === true ? 'comeoutside' : separateFirstFourWords('comeoutside')}}</p>
```

As you can see I wanna separate the two words and want a line break between these words
how can I achieve that in VUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the v-html directive for that:

`<p v-html="something === true ? 'comeoutside' : separateFirstFourWords('comeoutside')"></p>`

This will render the outcome of the ternary operator as HTML.

Be aware of the **cross site scripting vulnerabilities** this might create, though, see warning in [v-html documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#raw-html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`v-html`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html) :

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const separateFirstFourWords = (words) => {
      let newStr = `${words.substring(0, 4)} <br> ${words.substring(4, words.length)}`;
      return newStr;
    };
    const something = ref(true)
    return { separateFirstFourWords, something }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p v-html="something === true ? 'comeoutside' : separateFirstFourWords('comeoutside')"></p>
  <button @click="something = !something">change something</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `v-if`? That way your app will be safe against HTML/JS injections.

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const words = 'comeoutside'
    const something = ref(false)
    return { words, something }
  }
})
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-if="something"><p>{{words}}</p></div>
    <div v-else>
    <p>{{words.substring(0, 4)}}
    <br/>
    {{words.substring(4, words.length)}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v-html` directive as suggested by [Gabe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17438890/gabe) but yeah be aware of `XSS` attack.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    something: false,
    comeoutside: 'Hello VueJS !'
  },
  methods: {
    separateFirstFourWords(str, breakAt) {
      let newStr = `${str.substring(0, breakAt)} <br> ${str.substring(breakAt,str.length)}`;
      return newStr;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p v-html="something ? comeoutside : separateFirstFourWords(comeoutside, 5)"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that using CSS `white-space: pre-line;` and instead of using `<br>` and rendering using `v-html`, you can consider using `\n` so you can avoid `XSS` attack.

```html
<script setup>
const separateFirstFourWords = (words) => {
  let newStr = `${words.substring(0, 4)} \n ${words.substring(4,words.length)}`;
  return newStr;
};

</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <p v-text="separateFirstFourWords('comeoutside')"></p>
</template>

<style>
  p {
    white-space: pre-line;
  }
</style>
```